# R calculation based on the previous results step by step by group

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GRDH.png)I want to find out how many days are without supplies and how many days are with supplies in each period by group, I'm thinking to create a new variable of "Days". At first, I calculated the time interval between two dates next to each other "DateDiff", then I used the time interval "DateDiff" to minus the previous SupplyDays `lag(SupplyDays)` to get "DaysLeft", if the DaysLeft is >0, it means there is a supply shortage, and if the DaysLeft is <0, it means there is supply left, can be used in the following days. But it's only compared with the previous line, so more work needs to be done. It sounds complicated. But my purpose is to find out how many days are without supplies and how many days are with supplies in each period. The thing is that only previous left supplies can be used in the future, but the future left supplies can not be used in the past, so each step of the calculation is based on the previous result, and `cumsum()` dose not apply to my case. The first value of "Days" of each group is equal to "DaysLeft". Then if the previous "Days" is <0, the present "Days" should be the present "DaysLeft" plus the previous "Days" to cancel out supplies left from the past, if the previous 'Days" is >0, the present "Days" is equal to the present "DaysLeft".

```r
df <- data.frame(Group = c(3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1), 
                 Date = c(20190102, 20190207, 20190309, 20190417, 20190507, 20190610, 20190707, 20190808, 20190907, 20191018),
                 SupplyDays = c(80,9,40,7,35,7,2,60,1,5))
```

I tried to use `mutate()`, but the mutate function can not tell the new variable itself, so it cannot check >0 or <0.
Then I created a loop, but the loop sometimes work, sometimes does not. And I don't know how to group_by in the loop.

```r
df$Days[1] <- df$DaysLeft[1]
for (i in 2:length(df$DaysLeft)){
    if (df$Days[i-1]>=0){
        df$Days[i]<-df$DaysLeft[i]
    } else {
   df$Days[i]<-(df$DaysLeft[i]+df$Days[i-1])
  }
}
```

If you have any thoughts, I would be super appreciated! I'm new to R, and I've been working on this for days. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for asking, Ronak. I just added a picture of my expected output. I'm sorry, I even don't know how to make it as a R style output :(

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
  arrange(Group) %>% # for convenience
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), "%Y%m%d")) %>% # coerce dates to Date format
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(DateDiff = Date - lag(Date, 1)) %>% # calculate time difference with previous row
  mutate(DateDiff = replace_na(DateDiff, 0)) %>% # replace NA with 0
  mutate(DaysLeft = DateDiff - lag(SupplyDays,1)) %>%
  mutate(DaysLeft = replace_na(DaysLeft, 0)) %>%  # replace NA with 0
  mutate(Days = ifelse(lag(DaysLeft, 1) < 0, DaysLeft + lag(DaysLeft, 1), DaysLeft)) %>%
  mutate(Days = replace_na(Days, 0)) # replace NA with 0
```

With this output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Group [3]
   Group Date       SupplyDays DateDiff DaysLeft  Days
   <dbl> <date>          <dbl> <drtn>   <drtn>   <dbl>
 1     1 2019-03-09         40   0 days   0 days     0
 2     1 2019-05-07         35  59 days  19 days    19
 3     1 2019-07-07          2  61 days  26 days    26
 4     1 2019-09-07          1  62 days  60 days    60
 5     1 2019-10-18          5  41 days  40 days    40
 6     2 2019-04-17          7   0 days   0 days     0
 7     2 2019-06-10          7  54 days  47 days    47
 8     3 2019-01-02         80   0 days   0 days     0
 9     3 2019-02-07          9  36 days -44 days   -44
10     3 2019-08-08         60 182 days 173 days   129
```

UPDATE

I was thinking about this over the weekend and it may help to approach this problem differently. We are dealing with an inventory/consumption problem so here's a very simple approach.
We need to have proper definitions for this to work:

- Incoming: material arriving at the start of the period. I take that your `SupplyDays` is exactly this.
- Consumption: during the period we consume one day of inventory per day

We would need to calculate the inventory at the end of each period. So I created a slightly different data frame with columns `Date`, `Incoming` and `Inventory`. The assumption is that the first row is `period: 0` with only an existing inventory. The `Inventory` then becomes the sum of what I already have (`data$Inventory [i - 1]`), what is incoming in this period (`data$Incoming[i]`) and minus what I am consuming (`as.numeric(data$DateDiff[i])`).

```
data <- tibble(Date = c(20190309, 20190507, 20190707, 20190907, 20191018, 20191210, 20200120),
             Incoming = c(0, 35, 27, 108, 5, 12, 30),
             Inventory = c(40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

This `tibble` requires a bit of work:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), "%Y%m%d")) %>%
  mutate(DateDiff = Date - lag(Date, 1))  %>%# calculate time difference with previous row
  mutate(DateDiff = replace_na(DateDiff, 0))
```

And because I need to treat the first row differently than the other rows I need to use a for-loop:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
  if (i == 1) {
    data$Inventory [i] <- data$Inventory [i] + data$Incoming[i]
  } else {
    data$Inventory [i] <- data$Inventory [i - 1] + data$Incoming[i] - as.numeric(data$DateDiff[i])
  }
}
```

With this output:

```
> data
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  Date       Incoming Inventory DateDiff
  <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <drtn>  
1 2019-03-09        0        40  0 days 
2 2019-05-07       35        16 59 days 
3 2019-07-07       27       -18 61 days 
4 2019-09-07      108        28 62 days 
5 2019-10-18        5        -8 41 days 
6 2019-12-10       12       -49 53 days 
7 2020-01-20       30       -60 41 days
```

This can easily be expanded to include groups. Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, Pau!  I appreciate that so much! However, it's checking if DaysLeft >0 or <0, not the result "Days" of the previous step. For example, if the 10th "DaysLeft" is 20, instead of 173, the "Days" would be -24, and it should be added to the next "Days". Do you have any thoughts about that? Tons of thanks!

Comment: If I change the last date in Group 3 to force `DaysLeft` to equal 20 (2019-03-08) then I calculate `Days` as -24 for that row. If that is not correct, perhaps add some more rows to your example of output data. At this point it is not clear to me what is your requirement.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes, you're right. If you change the last date in Group 3 to 2019-03-08, the "Days" would be -24, "DaysLeft" would be 20. But if I have another observation of Group 3 at row 11, according to your code, the "Days" of row 11 would be equal to the "DaysLeft" of row 11, because the "DaysLeft" of row 10 is greater than 0. But I want the 24 days of the supplies left to be added to the row 11, it means I want to calculate row 11 based on the "Days" of row 10 instead of "DaysLeft". Your answer is so close. If you can take a look at it again, it would save a helpless me. Thank you!

Comment: @Zoe: I added a couple of more thoughts.

Comment: Thank you! Paul. I finally solved it with a similar loop. Thank you so much! Yours is much more clear! Wish you all the best!